# How do I set the value of an element in a hidden array to zero?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to total a number of rows based on their name.  It works fine as shown below...

```
var total = 0;
$("input[name$='-line_item_january']").each(function(index, element) {
    var val = parseFloat($(element).val());
    if (!isNaN(val)) {
         total += val;
    }
});
$("#id_january_disabled_total").val((total).toFixed(2));
$("#id_january_total").val((total).toFixed(2));
```

I am now running into an issue whereby if the user hides the row...the value of the -line_item_january is still being included in my totals because the line_item_january is not hidden but the array is.  From what I gather...from the rest of my program my best bet is to zero out the fields that are hidden in the array so that my computations are correct.

I tried to do something like...

```
$('[name=updatebudgetlineitem_set-1-line_item_january]').value = '0';
```

But it's not working.  Thanks in advance for any thoughts on what I might be doing incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how your "rows" are structured, you can add `:visible` to the selector, eg:

```
$("input[name$='-line_item_january']:visible").each(function(index, element) {
```

Alternatively, you can add/remove a class on the row/container and include that in the selector, eg:

```
$(".active input[name$=....`
```

Then when you hide the row, also remove that class from the container/row so that it affects all the inputs in the row/container - then the items that aren't in an active row/container won't be included.

---

Regarding setting the value='0' your line:

```
$('[name=updatebudgetlineitem_set-1-line_item_january]').value = '0';
```

mixes DOM methods and jquery, for jquery use `.val("0")`

```
$('[name=updatebudgetlineitem_set-1-line_item_january]').val("0")
```